# What is the のって supposed to mean here?

Tags: meaning, particle-の, particle-って

I'm translating a game and this is the sentence:

> 恭介が気に入るレア物のCDを探すのって....結構大変なんだよね.

What is the meaning of のって after 探す?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「Verb/Verb Phrase + の + って」

The 「の」 is a nominalizing particle.  It nominalizes the verb that precedes.  In meaning and usage, therefore, it is the same as 「こと」.

「って」 here is an **informal topic-introducing particle**.  In meaning, it is the same as 「～～というのは」.

Thus, 「～～を[探]{さが}すのって」 means "looking for ~~ (is)".

> 「[恭介]{きょうすけ}が[気]{き}に[入]{い}るレア[物]{もの}のCDを[探]{さが}すのって....[結構大変]{けっこうたいへん}なんだよね。」 means:
>
> "Looking for the rare CDs that Kyousuke would like... is pretty hard."